# How to transform a function to make it touch the x-axis?

Tags: graphing-functions

Say I have a function $f(x) = x^2 + 2$

This function never touches the x-axis, but it could be easily transformed to touch it by cancelling the constant as in $g(x) = (x^2 + 2) - 2$

Is there any way to generalize this, so that I can make any function "magnet" to the x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply letting $g(x)=f(x)-f(x_0)$ for any $x_0\in\mathbb R$ such that $f$ is well-defined at $x_0$ works

Comment: If I had $f(x) = x^4 + 3x^3 + 2x^2 + 2$ and I use this method, is works well, but is there any possible way to get the lowest part of the function to touch the x-axis rather than allowing part of it to overflow?

Answer (score -1):

if you mean touching in the sense that the x axes is a tangent o zur graph of f , than  f(x9) must have at least one point x0  with f'(x0)=0 then you just  take g(x)=f(x)-f(x0) and g touches the x- axes.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to express math at MathSE.